# How to insert the date as quarter in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, date

In Excel the quarter can be calculated by using a formula. How about in Word 2010? Is there a way to insert the current quarter such as "Q1-2008"? It should be an auto-updated field such as the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add Excel Cells into Microsoft Word, so this could be an option:
Go to 'Insert', find the Table option & click the down arrow.

In the list, select the option for 'Excel Spreadsheet'.
You can then enter your formula  & close the edit panel & it will leave you with a cell or group of cells (depending how many you want in your document) that should give you the information you need.

HTH

Comment: Your solution works perfectly apart from an auto-update problem I encounter now: I use the Today() function in the quarter formula. Unfortunately it is not executed when I open the word file. It executes when double clicking the inserted excel table though. But an auto-update on file opening would be much better. Do you know a solution for that problem too?

Comment: Hmm, not entirely sure on that one, the issue is likely to be because it is an Excel Spreadsheet within Word, so it will require the activation as you've found.  I will have a look about and see if there is anything that I can find to automate it for you - we may need to look at Macros or something like that.

Comment: Never mind. I can use another data source which allows me to it without an excel table.Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with nested field codes but I don't think it will autoupdate the way you probably want (AFAICR the DATE field itself is "special" like that)

```
{ DATE \@"'Q{ =INT(({ DATE \@M }+2)/3 }-' YYYY" }
```

where all the {} pairs are the special field code braces that you can insert on Windows Word using ctrl-F9.

(Not well-tested!)

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't get @bibadia's answer code to run (switch "\ M" unknown in Word 2003) I build this field function which should run in any Word version:

```
Q{=INT(({DATE \@M} + 2) / 3)}-{DATE \@YYYY}
```

Comment: Yes, should have been \@M (backslash-atsign-M), and your DATE \Q needs to be the same. (Ideally, you could have edited my answer or commented on it).

Comment: You're right, it's not magic - blanks or apostrophes after '\@' can be omitted. And the '\Q' switch should have been '\@'. Credit for the calculating field goes to you of course, thanks.